# Algorithm for scheduling jobs on processors

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, np-complete

**As per iehrlich's comment (thanks btw), the term "scheduling" might be misleading and this might be a more appropriate description: given a matrix N*N, find a row permutation that will yield the largest diagonal sum.**

I have a set of N jobs and N processors. All processors can be different from each other. For each (job, processor) pair, I have the performance of that job running on that processor. Performance is measured in IPC (Instructions Per Cycle).

I'm trying to find a schedule (1-to-1 allocation) that maximizes the overall sum of IPC. I can do it by going over all possible schedules, with O(N!), which is not viable.

I then tried to use the "stable matching" algorithm O(N^2), using the IPCs to sort the workloads' and the processors' preferences. It runs very fast and returns a decent schedule, but not the optimal one.

My questions are:

1) I really expected the stable matching algorithm to be able to return the optimal assignment. Can somebody explain why it fails? My best guess so far is the existence of ties between different (job, processor) pairs. I also tried the "stable matching with indifference" algorithm with no luck. **I should mention that the algorithm doesn't fail because of my implementation of it. I'm looking for a more theoretical answer as to why the algorithm itself cannot solve this problem.**

2) Do you know of an algorithm I can use for this? Does one even exist?

Comment: There's a whole computer science branch for that. Actually it originally comes from the production management. Consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing) for starters

Comment: Thanks, it looks quite helpful. However, after quickly skimming through it, it looks like all the algorithms presented are heuristics and are not guaranteed to return the optimal schedule.

Comment: I said "for starters" for a reason :) Also, how do you check if the schedule is optimal?

Comment: Oh wait, so N jobs and N processors is *not* a typo...

Comment: No it's not a typo. I have the same number of processors and jobs and I'm looking for assigning exactly one job to each one. I runt the O(N!) algorithm on small inputs (4,8,16 processors) to identify the optimal schedule. I should probably mention that all jobs were previously ran and profiled for each processor, so I do not have to actually run them each time. I simply evaluate the returned schedule.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in understanding why the stable matching algorithm fails to be honest. I'm pretty sure there's not a good way to solve this. The "Hungarian algorithm" looks promising ( O(N^4) ), but I don't want to implement it just to realize that it also doesn't work :).

Comment: In this case, the term 'scheduling' is misleading. It actually has nothing to do with job scheduling whatsoever - it's purely mathematical task - **given a matrix N*N, find a row permutation that will yield the largest diagonal sum**.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in why the algorithm fails, you should provide the code that fails with an input, actual output and desired output.

Comment: This looks a lot like a TSP problem if you use dynamic programming to solve it.

Comment: if you just want to prototype quickly, scipy has an implementation of the Hungarian algorithm so you don't need to implement it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why stable matching is the wrong algorithm is that you can wind up with a matching where a pair of processors would each prefer each other's jobs, but one of the jobs prefers the processor that it is on.  Switching makes someone worse off, so this matching is stable.

However in your problem we care if the global optimum.  If the improvement in one job exceeds how much worse the other gets, you want to switch.  For the global optimum being a stable matching is necessary but not sufficient.

The Hungarian algorithm in fact is the right one to to find the globally optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just tried the Hungarian algorithm using the scipy implementation. It returns the optimal schedule (I think the scipy implementation might be O(N^3) but I'm not sure). Thanks to iehrlich and user3080953 for their very valuable comments. And thanks to you of course btilly!

Comment: Just FYI, I had to negate the IPC measurements since the Hungarian algorithm minimizes the cost (instead of maximizing it)